# `super` with a class and its metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

The signature is: `super([type[, object-or-type]])`. And its [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) says:

> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound. If the second argument is an object, `isinstance(obj, type)` must be true. If the second argument is a type, `issubclass(type2, type)` must be true (this is useful for classmethods).

According to the doc, if someone wants `super(metatype, type)`, the second argument is a type, so `issubclass(type, metatype)` must be true. But my test program shows it can be false:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class M0(type):
    def wtf(self):
        print('M0')

class M1(M0):
    def wtf(self):
        print('M1')

class C0(metaclass=M1):
    @classmethod
    def wtf(cls):
        assert issubclass(C0, M1) == False
        super(M1, C0).wtf()

C0.wtf()
```

Is this guaranteed or undefined?

Comment: Interesting question, I thought it's undefined behavior, waiting for others' answers.

Comment: The difference, I suppose, lies between `type` and `object`. `C0` is an instance of type `M1`, not a subclass of `M1`.
For more details on metaclasses that you used in your example, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python